# How to compile C code containing extern "C" directive?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, extern

In Visual Studio 2008, there's a nice debug heap coded in file `dbgheap.c`.  It implements functions such as `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`.

I note the file includes `extern "C"` directives that don't seem to be allowed by Microsoft's own compiler.  Code like:

```
extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(
    void
    )
{
    /* only dump leaks when there are in fact leaks */
```

Simply produces errors if you try to compile it yourself.  Obviously there are compiler flags to allow this syntax, but anyone know what the flags are?

Comment: Well, there is such a flag - `/Tp`, aka "compile as C++ regardless of extension". `extern "C"` is a C++ construct.

Comment: Granted that extern "C" is a C++ construct; I've however seen compiler flags that allow C-isms in C++ and vice versa, hence the question.  Ultimately I've determined that while the file in question is pure C except for this construct, it does happen to compile perfectly with /TP (VS08 gives it with capital P) so I arrived at the same answer as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it turns out that while the code is otherwise 100% legal C, except for these `extern "C"` qualifiers, it also compiles perfectly with flag `/TP` which means, "compile as C++ disregarding the file name."

So, I imagine that's what they did.

I think MSFT just overlooked putting the `extern "C"` qualifiers in some sort of conditional compilation dependent on the `__cplusplus` flag or something.

Comment: Many of the C Runtime sources with a .c extension are actually compiled as C++.

Comment: Just curious as to why?  For instance would I be well-advised to do the same thing with a large library of mine that's mostly C but some C++ and normally used in C++ apps?

Comment: No. Definitely don't do this. If you have C++ code, use a C++ file extension like cpp (or maybe cxx). The C Runtime sources in question started off as C source files then were very gradually C++ified.  Often the files were just not renamed as that process went along. (When we did a major redesign of the C Runtime for Windows 10 and Visual C++ 2015, we rectified this and fixed all of the file extensions.)